# What is the correct way to use LEFT JOINS, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY together?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Query (MySQL) which uses a combination of LEFT JOIN, GROUP BUY, ORDER BY, and LIMIT. When I remove LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY it works fine. What is the correct way to add in my additional LEFT JOIN and GROUP logic to make this work?

```
SELECT tbl_headlines.*, count(tbl_weekly_builds.id) as related_count 
    FROM tbl_headlines 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_weekly_builds ON tbl_headlines.id = tbl_weekly_builds.headline 
    GROUP BY tbl_headlines.id 
    WHERE tbl_headlines.deleted is null 
    ORDER BY LOWER(tbl_headlines.label) asc 
    LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Comment: What columns do you really need in your result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect - `where clause` will be before `group by`

```
SELECT tbl_headlines.id, count(tbl_weekly_builds.id) as related_count 
    FROM tbl_headlines 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_weekly_builds ON tbl_headlines.id = tbl_weekly_builds.headline 
    WHERE tbl_headlines.deleted is null 
    GROUP BY tbl_headlines.id 
    ORDER BY LOWER(tbl_headlines.label) asc 
    LIMIT 0, 100;
```

Comment: Lower is surely irrelevant in this context

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! Yes, I should have made the query simpler by removing the LOWER part.